# How to draw filled polyogon in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, path

I need to fill with color an area of given polygon on a custom view. I can't find a method with which I can use for this matter.

I can actually only draw lines connecting those point but I'm unsure how to fill the area surrounded by them.

The following code I use to draw lines:

```java
for (Path p : paths) {
                Paint color = p.getColor();
                float strokeW = color.getStrokeWidth();
                color.setStrokeWidth(pthStrokeWdth);

                List<Point> currentPath = p.getCoordinateList();
                for (int i = 1; i < currentPath.size(); i++) {
                    float startX = currentPath.get(i - 1).x;
                    float startY = currentPath.get(i - 1).y;
                    float endX = currentPath.get(i).x;
                    float endY = currentPath.get(i).y;
                    canvas.drawLine((startX * cellWidth) + xOffset + halfCellWidth, (startY * cellHeight) + yOffset + halfCellHeight,
                            (endX * cellWidth) + xOffset + halfCellWidth, (endY * cellHeight) + yOffset + halfCellHeight, color);

                }
                color.setStrokeWidth(originalStrokeWidth);
 }
```

The above draw lines between every point forming polygons with diverse shapes. See below screenshot.

[image]

So I would likne to fill the area inside the polygone like below:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Paint.Style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html) to `FILL` or `FILL_AND_STROKE`

`paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);`

Edit:

```
    Paint color = p.getColor();
    float strokeW = color.getStrokeWidth();
    color.setStrokeWidth(pthStrokeWdth);
    color.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    List<Point> currentPath = p.getCoordinateList();
    //for each path we want to draw a line which consist of 4 points
    float[] points = new float[currentPath.size() * 4];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < currentPath.size(); i++) {
        float startX = currentPath.get(i - 1).x;
        float startY = currentPath.get(i - 1).y;
        float endX = currentPath.get(i).x;
        float endY = currentPath.get(i).y;
        points[count++] = (startX * cellWidth) + xOffset + halfCellWidth;
        points[count++] = (startY * cellHeight) + yOffset + halfCellHeight;
        points[count++] = (endX * cellWidth) + xOffset + halfCellWidth;
        points[count++] = (endY * cellHeight) + yOffset + halfCellHeight, color;
    }
    canvas.drawLines(points, color);
```

Comment: @Krul Probably not I believe by default it ignores the style but you can probably use `drawLines` instead

Comment: I already draw lines, what I need now is to fill the area surrounded by the lines.

Comment: @Krul Yes I know I'm saying instead of using `drawLine` you can use `drawLines` or possible use `drawRect(RectF rect, Paint paint)`

Comment: Hummm... well but the shapes aren't not always rectangular.

Comment: @Krul I know that's why I was saying to use drawLines, check main post

Comment: Saw your modifications.I'm going to try out and let you know

Comment: Is this a typo: ```points[count++] = (endY * cellHeight) + yOffset + halfCellHeight, color;``` ? This seems to require 3 arguments

Comment: @Krul Yes my bad remove the `, color;` I copy pasted arguements from your drawLine call and didnt notice lol

Comment: Removed the last argumen(_color_), and the result is still the same: Lines are drawn but the are is not filled

Comment: @Krul Hmm seems you wont be able to fill with drawLines which I guess makes sense. The only other option I can think of is to construct your shape using one or more `RectF` then use `drawRect(rectF, paint)` with paint having style of fill

Comment: That's why I posted this question in first place. I need a method to help me fill that area. Drawing lines is already done.

Comment: @Krul Well can't help there. If it was only a rectangle that'd be fine but other shapes, not sure. I think it'd also be worth looking into `drawBitmap`, creating a bitmap with the coordinates of the space inside you need to fill.

Comment: Thanks, will try your suggestion